# Getting IMSI Number of Duel Sim Card

Tags: android

I am developing Android Anti-theft Application in Which when your Android Mobile Phone Is Stolen and the theft change the Sim a message will be sent to the trusted user through Thief Sim .

> I have Done The Single Sim Change Event Module by getting the IMSI of Sim card but how i get The Dual Sim IMEI .

Please Help Me with the Correct Working Code This is my Final Year Project

```html
public String getSubscriberId(){
    operator = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String IMSI = operator.getSubscriberId();
    return IMSI;
}

simID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
    simIMSI = getSubscriberId().toString();

    if (simIMSI.equals("")){
        simID.setText("No SIM card detected!");
    }
    else{
        simID.setText(simIMSI.toString());
        SaveUniqueId(simIMSI.toString());
    }
```

Comment: This Code Is For Single IMSI but HOw I Get The DUEl SIM IMSI NUMber Or Serial Number

Comment: I think this was not possible up till now for the dual Sim but android have somehow given it a way to use it in lollipop version.

Answer (score -2):

```
 TelephonyInfo telephonyInfo = TelephonyInfo.getInstance(this);

  String imsiSIM1 = telephonyInfo.getImsiSIM1();
  String imsiSIM2 = telephonyInfo.getImsiSIM2();
```

Comment: Could you provide some details on the code for future readers